# mysql counts the number of new visitors by day

Tags: mysql

MySQL version: 5.7
Here is **users** table:

```
+------------+------+
| date       | uid |
+------------+------+
| 2020-06-29 05:00:00 | 352  |
| 2020-06-29 08:00:00 | 354  |
| 2020-06-29 09:25:53 | 354  |
| 2020-06-30 08:00:00 | 863  |
| 2020-06-30 09:00:01 | 352  |
| 2020-06-30 09:59:59 | 352  |
| 2020-07-01 07:00:00 | 358  |
| 2020-07-01 09:00:00 | 358  |
+------------+------+
```

I want to count the number of new visitors per day,But there is an important condition here that new visitors of the day cannot be visited before.

**I want the result**:

```
Result:
+------------+------------------+
| date       | new_user_count   |
+------------+------------------+
| 2020-06-29 |         2        |
| 2020-06-30 |         1        |
| 2020-07-01 |         1        |
+------------+------------------+
```

The above result is equivalent to these three sql:

```
2020-06-29 (352,354) : select count( distinct uid ) as new_user_count from users where DATE(date) = '2020-06-29' and uid not in ( select distinct uid from users where date < '2020-06-29 05:00:00'); #2 
2020-06-30 (863): select count( distinct uid ) as new_user_count from users where DATE(date)= '2020-06-30' and uid not in ( select distinct uid from users where date < '2020-06-30 08:00:00'); # 1
2020-07-01 (358): select count( distinct uid ) as new_user_count from users where DATE(date)= '2020-07-01' and uid not in ( select distinct uid from users where date < '2020-07-01 07:00:00'); # 1
```

I haven't thought of it until now, thanks
Here is [Online users table](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2c6ee7/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a correlated subquery to check if each user visit be the first or not:

```
SELECT
    date,
    SUM(CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM users u2
                              WHERE u2.date < u1.date AND u2.uid = u1.uid)
             THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS new_user_count
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT date, uid FROM users) u1
GROUP BY
    date;
```

[image]

### Demo

The above logic actually reads straightforward, and says to count a user record only if we cannot find that same user appearing in the table at some later date.  Note that I use distinct selects, because it appears that in your data a given user might appear more than once on the same date.  This data would spoof the above correlated subquery, so we ensure that a given user appear only once on a given date (and besides, one user can only be counted once per day anyway).

Comment: thanks，this is helpful,I can easily understand your sql

Comment: Use `DATE(date)` in place of just `date`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  date,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT u1.uid)
    FROM users u1 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(
      SELECT * FROM users u2
      WHERE u2.uid = u1.uid AND u2.date < u0.date
    ) AND u1.date = u0.date
  )
FROM
  users u0
GROUP BY
  date
;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-- get date and the amount of distinct users
SELECT date, COUNT(DISTINCT uid)
-- from users table
FROM users
-- only when there not exists a row
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL      -- may use any literal value instead of NULL
                   -- in the table
                   FROM users u
                   -- with this user id
                   WHERE users.uid = u.uid
                   -- but earlier (less) date
                     AND users.date > u.date )
GROUP BY date;
```